# Is there any way to output "monitor" objects value in real time as text/values in Salabim?

Tags: python, simulation

I know we can use animatemonitor to have a synchronized real-time value of monitor objects value and display as a graph over the built-in display/gui, but I have a requirement to use those values/plot in another graph in a browser. So i need those raw data in a synchronized real time manner. Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is start the animation (possibly with a minimized window and no further functionality) and create your own `Environment.animation_pre_tick()` method that emits the values you want to show in another way.

Something like:

```
import salabim as sim

class RealTimeEnvironment(sim.Environment):
    def animation_pre_tick(self, t):
        ... # put your emitting code here at time=t
    
env = RealTimeEnvironment()

env.animate(True)
env.run(sim.inf)
```

Comment: Thanks or the quick response sir, it worked like a charm, just one small thing, it would be great if it's somehow possible to remove the GUI completly.